# When (void *) p == (void *) *p - What does the Standard say about this?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, language-lawyer, standards

Example:

```c
int a[99];
int (*p)[99] = &a;

// this prints 1
printf("%d\n", (void *) p == (void *) *p);
```

In general, if `p` is a pointer to an array, then both the object representations (i.e. the bit patterns) of `p` and `*p` are equal.

I'm just lost and completely unsure about the portability of this behaviour.

So, I'm curious whether this behaviour is guaranteed by the Standard. If so, could someone please quote all of the relevant paragraphs that guarantee it?

Comment: `p` points to the array as a whole, while `*p` points to the first element of the array. But these happen to share the same address. Similarly a pointer to a struct and a pointer to the structs first member would share the same address as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comparison is guaranteed to be 1.

The relevant part of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) is section 6.5.9p6 regarding the equality operator and the comparison of pointers:

> Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both
> are pointers to the same object (**including a pointer to an object and
> a subobject at its beginning**) or function, both are pointers to one
> past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer to
> one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the
> start of a different array  object  that  happens  to  immediately
> follow  the  first  array  object  in  the  address space.

Take particular note of the passage in bold.  This means two things: 1) a pointer to a struct and a pointer to its first member (suitable converted) will compare equal, and 2) a pointer to an array and a pointer to its first member (again, suitable converted) will compare equal.

In your particular case, `p` points to an array and `*p` is the array itself, and using `*p` in an expression yields a pointer to its first member.  Both are converted to `void *` to give them a common type.  So this comparison will always evaluate to 1.

Comment: There's something wrong with this argument; though it's hard to say what exactly. For one of the historical platforms, if you tried this argument with `char *` and `char **` they would not be bit equivalent because `char *` had a different machine representation than all other pointer types. They would compare equal only because the type conversion would convert the bits.

Comment: @Joshua I don't think they necessarily have to be bit equivalent.  A `void *` is capable of holding any object pointer, so the conversion process should be able to account for that.  There's nothing that says two pointers need to be bit equivalent to be equal.  In the floating point world, +0 and -0 have different IEEE754 representations but compare equal.

Answer (score 1):

> In general, if `p` is a pointer to an array, then both the object representations (i.e. the bit patterns) of `p` and `*p` are equal.

If `p` is a pointer to an array, then `*p` is the array. The bit representation of the array is the concatenation of the bit representations of the elements of the array (because C 2018 6.2.5 20 says an array is made of contiguously allocated objects). The bits in the array are not generally equal to the bits in the pointer.

However, when an array is used in an expression other than as the operand of unary `&` or the operand of `sizeof` or as a string literal used to initialize an array, the array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. The first element of the array `*p` is `(*p)[0]`, so `*p` is automatically converted to `&(*p)[0]`.

Then the question is whether `(void *) p` equals `(void *) &(*p)[0]`.

C 2018 6.3.2.3 1 tells us any pointer to an object type may be converted to `void *`. However, it does not tell us what the results of comparisons are while the pointer is `void *`. It does tell us that converting the `void *` back to its original type yields a pointer that compares equal to the original.

C 2018 6.5.9 6 tells us “Two pointers compare equal if and only if …, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning)…” (I elided some other cases that are not of concern here.) What are we to make of this given two `void *`? It seems the intent is for a pointer to “point to an object” even if it is currently in the form of a `void *`. Then `(void *) p` points to the array and `(void *) &(*p)[0]` points to a subobject at its beginning, so they compare equal.

The semantics would be clearer with `(char *) p == (char *) *p` because C 2018 6.3.2.3 7 tells us that converting to `char *` produces a pointer to the first byte of an object, and the first byte of an array is the same as the first byte of its first element.

Comment: Oh, right. I was completely careless. I was aware of the conversion rules myself. I’ll insert an edit in my question above.